# Laptop charging reminder utility

Tags: windows-7, battery, reminder

My ASUS Windows 7 laptop naturally tells me when the battery is getting low. But I like to keep it charged whenever possible, and sometimes I forget to plug in.

Where is a simple program/utility/other method of creating a charging-reminder alert that happens every time the computer wakes up or turns on and is unplugged?

Answer (score 1):

I used [Battery Bar Pro](http://batterybarpro.com/) until my battery died. (Naturally, not because of the software.)
It's awesome.

(I'm not the developer, saw the software mentioned here first.)

Comment: Hmm, it looks pretty good, but even the paid version doesn't seem to provide what I'm specifically looking for. Every time my machine is opened, it should say "It looks like you're not plugged in," unless of course that's false. All I see in the Battery Bar Pro pictures is customizing the notifications based on battery level alone.

Comment: @Lenoxus: Download Visual Studio C# Express. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945986/find-out-battery-status-in-c-sharp-or-net | Write a veeeery simple app that like pops up a message whenever you hit the limits you want. That's it.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that when I find the time. Thanks, Shiki!

Comment: @Lenoxus: You will need to create a Windows GUI app (there is such an item at New Project). Copy-paste this code there. (Figure out the basics, not hard.) Then you need a tray icon I suppose. Just Google that as well. Try copy-pasting things. If you get stuck, mention me here, or create a Q on Stackoverflow. Such is life of a modern developer... :)) || And in the end, you need a sound effect, and a messagebox (Google it, simple, this is how it's called.) 4 things.

Comment: Changed my mind, I'll make an app today, like in a few hours.